# Align Android TextViews with different line numbers

Tags: android, textview, alignment

i'm trying to align n textviews in which there can be a different number of lines centered vertically and horizontally, and the textviews with more lines "fall" down, even if they have fixed size and center alignment. Is it possible to align them **by code?**

this is my xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="one line"
        android:textSize="48dp"
        tools:context=".MainActivity" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="two lines"
        android:textSize="48dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and this is my java class:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        TextView oneline=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        TextView twolines=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        twolines.setText("two lines \n two lines");
        oneline.setHeight(200);
        twolines.setHeight(200);
        oneline.setWidth(400);
        twolines.setWidth(400);
        oneline.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
        twolines.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
        oneline.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        twolines.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);     
    }
```

and this is the outcome :-\ 
[image: skew]

Comment: Remove Gravity  

    oneline.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
     twolines.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER); and align them in xml

Comment: @Pragnani thanks, but the purpose is to leave them centered vertically and horizontally

Comment: Do you want to design it only for tabletes..?

Comment: @Pragnani yes, it's for a tablet application. i noticed the same error is given when changing the textsize... the textview falls down

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why it happens but, the problem goes away when you change your layout to relative.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="one line"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        tools:context=".MainActivity" />


    <TextView
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/textView1"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:background="@color/abs__holo_blue_light"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="two lines
two lines"
android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textSize="20sp"
         />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**EDIT**
Actually it was just baseline_alignment issue.
Here is the code based solution.

```
        TextView oneline=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        TextView twolines=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        twolines.setText("two lines \n ywo lines");
        oneline.setHeight(200);
        twolines.setHeight(200);
        oneline.setWidth(400);
        twolines.setWidth(400);
        oneline.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
        twolines.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);


        oneline.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        twolines.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

        ViewParent v = ((View) oneline).getParent();
        ((LinearLayout) v).setBaselineAligned(false);
```

Comment: unfortunately i should fix that problem only by code, because the textviews i am creating are cells and they must go into a tablelayout

Comment: Does the issue even happen if you wrap it in a tablerow, though?

Comment: yes because each row into a tableview uses a linearlayout and it cannot be changed to relativelayout like @kaya suggested

Comment: @kaya works perfectly, thanks! It was indeed the auto base alignment!